# Transferring data between strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf, strcpy

I'm trying to get this code to work, however I can't see any problems with it. Scores are inputted for each of the 8 games, and then the winner's name is meant to be imported into a new name array. However, the logic only seems to work on certain data when inputted.

```
void firstWinner(char firstScore[PLAYERS][SCORE], 
char name[PLAYERS][LEN], char quarterName[QUARTERPLAYERS][LEN])
{
    int playerOneWinCount = 0;
    int playerTwoWinCount = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    int x = 0;


    for(i=0; i < PLAYERS; i+=2, x++)
    {

        for(j=0; j < SCORE; j++)
        {
            if(firstScore[i][j] > firstScore[i+1][j])
            {
                playerOneWinCount++;
            }
            else if(firstScore[i][j] < firstScore[i+1][j])
            {
                playerTwoWinCount++;
            }

        }

        if(playerOneWinCount > playerTwoWinCount)
        {

            strcpy(quarterName[x], name[i]);
        }
        else if(playerOneWinCount < playerTwoWinCount)
        {
            strcpy(quarterName[x], name[i+1]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This `for(i=0; i < PLAYERS; i+=2, x++)` seems wrong! Do you know the `%` operator?

Comment: Also, could you provide input sample data and the expected output?

Comment: @iharob he is skipping every other player, while a source of possible error I don't think it's wrong.

Comment: here strcpy(quarterName[x], name[i+1]); you use i+1 with i = (PLAYER-1) but name has only (PLAYER-1) strings.

Comment: `quarterName` should contain `PLAYERS / 2` players apparently, think about it!

Comment: It needs to compare two players each time e.g. player 1 vs player 2, player 3 vs player 4. This means i needs to increment by two every time so no player is compared more than once.

Comment: QUARTERPLAYERS = PLAYERS / 2 - It is named QUARTERPLAYERS  because it's the quarter finals of a game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the win count values to 0 at the beginning of the players loop.